# Power BI - "Expression.Error: The column of the table wasn't found

Tags: powerbi

This error pops up randomly when I import data to Power BI using Supermetrics API about a day after when trying to refresh.
For example, using Adobe Analytics data, when I try to refresh my dashboard a day later, I sometimes get this error, saying [image]

When I click on "Go to error" it takes me to Changed type step, but I see that the code remains the same as I first imported it.
Going to Navigation step, I see that the data has changed, but I don't know why, since I haven't changed anything since I pulled data to Power BI.

What it used to look like:
[image]

vs what it looks like now
[image]

I have tried seeking help from Microsoft community, but no use, since most topics suggest changes to the code, which I haven't done.

Answer (score 1):

This is 100% an issue in import, and as this issue has only just come up now it is due to a change in source format.

Looking at the breakdown of your imported data, it seems as though you are accessing a web source? This makes me think that the html make-up of that webpage has changed.

Unfortunately, the easiest way of dealing with something like this, is to rebuild the query from the ground up. If you are still struggling, let me know and I will have a look into it further.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, the 'Date' column is not arriving from the data feed (Supermetrics API) during your refresh. When you come across this issue, read the data feed in other Power BI window or check in the source so that you can confirm, the 'Date' column is missing during a particular point in time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I found that when my data source changed in terms of column header name, this error was thrown. You probably already sorted it out by now, but any future readers, I would double check the source to make sure no changes were made that might affect this, and then if the source is unchanged in it's version history, then rebuild the inquiry again. It sucks if this is due to a PBI issue, but these two methods should solve 99% of the instances of this error.